# Highlight polygons incident at a vertex

Tags: python, geopandas

How do I create a *---`dict` might be best---* of all the polygons, in a GeoDataFrame, incident at a vertex. The polygons will intersect but never cross.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polys = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2, 1.5), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                     Polygon([(0,2), (2,2), (2,4), (0,4)]),
                     Polygon([(2,0), (5,0), (5,1.5), (2,1.5)]),
                     Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])

fp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys, 'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
fp.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.3, cmap='tab10', edgecolor='k',)
fp.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x['name'], xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'), axis=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
for i, row in fp.iterrows():
    oring = list(row.geometry.exterior.coords)#, row['ground_height']
    if row.geometry.exterior.is_ccw == False:
        #-- to get proper orientation of the normals
        oring.reverse() 
    for (j, v) in enumerate(oring[:-1]):
        print([oring[j][0], oring[j][1], row['name']])
```

```py
[0.0, 0.0, 'a']
[2.0, 0.0, 'a']
[2.0, 1.5, 'a']
[2.0, 2.0, 'a']
[0.0, 2.0, 'a'] 
[0.0, 2.0, 'b']  
[2.0, 2.0, 'b']  
[2.0, 4.0, 'b']  
[0.0, 4.0, 'b']
[2.0, 0.0, 'c']
[5.0, 0.0, 'c']
[5.0, 1.5, 'c']
[2.0, 1.5, 'c']
[3.0, 3.0, 'd']  
[5.0, 3.0, 'd']  
[5.0, 5.0, 'd']  
[3.0, 5.0, 'd']
```

So at the 1st vertex we should have:
a;
2nd: a, c;
3rd: a, c;
4rd: a, b;
5rd: a, b;
6th: b, a;
7th: b, a;
8th: b; and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, and I think you've already done most of the work! To get what you want (a dictionary that shows per vertex which polygons it intersects), I also think a dictionary would be easiest. Obtained by adjusting your code:

```
dict_vertices = {}
for i, row in fp.iterrows():
    oring = list(row.geometry.exterior.coords)#, row['ground_height']
    if row.geometry.exterior.is_ccw == False:
        #-- to get proper orientation of the normals
        oring.reverse() 
    for (j, v) in enumerate(oring[:-1]):
        vertex = (oring[j][0], oring[j][1])
        pol_name = row['name']
        if vertex in dict_vertices.keys():
            dict_vertices[vertex].append(pol_name)
        else:
            dict_vertices[vertex] = [pol_name]
```

Gives:

```
print(dict_vertices)
---
{(0.0, 0.0): ['a'],
 (2.0, 0.0): ['a', 'c'],
 (2.0, 1.5): ['a', 'c'],
 (2.0, 2.0): ['a', 'b'],
 (0.0, 2.0): ['a', 'b'],
 (2.0, 4.0): ['b'],
 (0.0, 4.0): ['b'],
 (5.0, 0.0): ['c'],
 (5.0, 1.5): ['c'],
 (3.0, 3.0): ['d'],
 (5.0, 3.0): ['d'],
 (5.0, 5.0): ['d'],
 (3.0, 5.0): ['d']}
```

Comment: Thank you @Thijs; how would I go about creating a nested `dict`. {polygon name: {vertex: list of incident attributes. something like ['grnd', 'rf', 'ot'}}? I want the duplicate vertex entries please.